# ARM SIGSEGV on a MOV instruction

Tags: android, gdb, arm, remote-debugging

When remote debugging on the android emulator a have a SIGSEGV on a `mov` instruction.

I don't understand how the mov an cause a SIGSEGV.
Bellow is the gdb session:

```
0x000080c0 in ?? ()
(gdb) disassemble 0x80c0,0x80e0
Dump of assembler code from 0x80c0 to 0x80e0:
=> 0x000080c0:  mov     r0, sp
   0x000080c4:  mov     r1, #0
   0x000080c8:  add     r2, pc, #4
   0x000080cc:  add     r3, pc, #4
   0x000080d0:  b       0x18998
   0x000080d4:  b       0x189a0
   0x000080d8:  andeq   r11, r1, r0
   0x000080dc:  andeq   r11, r1, r8
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) stepi
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000140b2 in ?? ()
(gdb) info register
r0             0xfffffffc       4294967292
r1             0xbeb91c13       3199802387
r2             0x0      0
r3             0x80d8   32984
r4             0x80d8   32984
r5             0xfffffffc       4294967292
r6             0x1b224  111140
r7             0xfffffffc       4294967292
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x0      0
sp             0xbeb91acc       0xbeb91acc
lr             0x14dcf  85455
pc             0x140b2  0x140b2
cpsr           0x80000030       -2147483600
```

More info in the state before the execution:

```
(gdb) info register
r0             0x0      0
r1             0xbe877c14       3196550164
r2             0x0      0
r3             0x0      0
r4             0x0      0
r5             0x0      0
r6             0x0      0
r7             0x0      0
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x0      0
sp             0xbe877b00       0xbe877b00
lr             0x0      0
pc             0x80c0   0x80c0
cpsr           0x10     16
```

So the execution is not in thumb.

EDIT: 
As @artlessnoise suggest here is more details: I am running on the Android emulator, the device is the Nexus One and it is the version 4.4 of android.

The gdb session here is at the very beginning of the program. It is just after the command:

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:5003
```

I have only one thread before and after the stepi.

Comment: PS is at 0x140b2 not on 0x80c0.

Comment: You mean PC, but it is after stepi.

Comment: What are the initial values of PC and CPSR?  Perhaps the core is initially in Thumb state?

Comment: But then why don't you disassemble that part? May be stepi is doing more than a single instruction?

Comment: The first line of the dump is where pc is initially: `0x000080c0 in ?? ()`

Comment: @scott How do I know if the core is in thumb?

Comment: Does the "=>" mean this is the address you asked to disassemble or does it mean this is the PC?  I'd do 'p/x $pc' to be sure. The T bit of the CPSR ((1<<5) or 0x20) says if the core is in Thumb state.

Comment: @scott yes => means the value of $pc.  I have double check it. Judging by the CPSR I am not in thumb.

Comment: Hmm, what does readelf say the entrypoint of your executable is? The processor is in Thumb state when the SEGV is reported.  What do you see if disass around the final PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the issue was due to the remote gdb. I need to `file` the executable before I start to run the program. After that the it get executed correctly.

```
(gdb) file myexe
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how the `mov` an cause a SIGSEGV.

It doesn't.

You are running with `cpsr` set to 0x10, which is user mode ARM state with *interrupts* and *FIQ* enabled.  Is your debugger task aware or system?  You haven't given enough info about the system.   What is at location 0x140b2 and 0x14dcf (Ie, what routines/code)?  The stack has changed by a large amount, so you did not run a single cycle.

### System debugging

An interrupt/FIQ may alter control flow.  Another possibility is a page fault.

### Task aware

If it is a task aware, a signal can alter control on a `stepi`.  Do you have a multi-threaded application?  Using `info threads` maybe helpful.

Sometimes debuggers will write a temporary *break point* at the next instruction and run; this doesn't mean they only step one instruction.  Signals, interrupts, page faults may all alter execution before the temporary *break point* is hit.  A `stepi` doesn't mean that the instruction the PC is at has caused the exception.

Comment: Especially the code/assembler preceding 0x000080c0 maybe helpful.  Was a device just written to?  Etc.

Comment: 0x000080c0 is the entry point of the program. I have double check with readelf. I have update the post with more info. Thanks for pointing the fact that stepi is not necessary executing only the next instruction.

Comment: Ah, if gdb knows the executable, then it tries to skip start-up code and get to the first line of `main()`.  You need to use another option to debug start-up code.  See [gdb startup](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html)

Comment: I have set a breakpoint just after 0x80c4, like the gdb man says. But I am still getting the SIGSEGV. I am wondering if the android emulator support debugging native application. I should try on the real device.

Comment: I found that the issue was that the remote gdb didn't know the executable so I need to `file` it. After that it work correctly. I wonder why it need that. I thought that all was handle by the target gdb.